# JavaScript tablet detection

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablet

**Requirement - Detect tablets using JavaScript**

I'm not allowed to use any plugin or lib (jQuery is an exception) and want to keep code to minimum.

I have read many posts on this topic and came up with this solution (Checking screen resolution and touch):

```
var _w = Math.max($(window).width(), $(window).height());
var _h = Math.min($(window).width(), $(window).height());

var tabletView = (_w >= 1000 && _h >= 600);

var is_touch_device = 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement;

if (tabletView && is_touch_device) {
    alert('tablet');
}
else {
    alert('Not a Tablet');
}​
```

**Question**: Is this code reliable enough? If not what's the better approach?

Comment: Many PCs are now available with both mouse and touch support.

Comment: Exactly, what's the alternative? User agents?

Comment: If you want to manually parse them, yes, user agents are an option.

Comment: Should I consider using minimum and maximum screen resolution? Assuming most of touch screen desktops will have bigger screens?

Comment: The alternative is not to detect "tablets". Detect features. Add certain functionality only if touch events are supported; add certain page elements only if a certain minimum size exists. There are too many variables where mobile devices  are concerned today, and a truly responsive site doesn't care about whether it's viewed on a "tablet" or "smartphone" or "desktop", but only about what functionality is available. For this, http://modernizr.com is the go-to tool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will also see phones with larger screen resolutions as tablets.

Other than that, this code is reliable, and there isn't really anything you could do to detect the difference between a phone and tablet, without libraries, or manually parsing user-agents.